# Pass variables from one job to an other in an azure multi stage pipeline (YAML)

Tags: azure-devops, yaml, azure-pipelines, multistage-pipeline

I have a very basic YAML azure pipeline

```
jobs:
- job: Foo
  steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "Create variable xyz"
      echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=xyz;]yes"
    displayName: 'Determine slot name'
  - bash: |
     echo "Var is: $(xyz)"
    displayName: 'Show variable'
- job: Bar
  dependsOn: Foo
  steps:
  - bash: |
      echo "Hello world $(Foo.xyz)"
    displayName: 'Show variable'
```

In the first JOB, named `Foo`, the variable `xyz` is set to `yes`. Which works, because I can display it in the seconds step with the line

```
echo "Var is: $(xyz)"
```

However, I would like to use that variable in the next job (named `Bar`). But whatever I do it does not exist. I tried things like

```
 echo "Hello world $(xyz)"
```

or

```
 echo "Hello world $(Foo.xyz)"
```

But both give the following error when I run the pipeline

```
 line 1: Foo.xyz: command not found
```

How can I share that variable between jobs? and sharing between stages would be nice too!!

Comment: more detailed explanation with sample source code explained [here](https://rollendxavier.medium.com/sharing-variables-between-stages-in-azure-devops-pipelines-59eb8decf3b0)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

So you have here actually two things.

**Pass variables from job to job which is possible:**

Did you try [multi job output variable](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-a-multi-job-output-variable):

```
jobs:

# Set an output variable from job A
- job: A
  pool:
    vmImage: 'vs2017-win2016'
  steps:
  - powershell: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=myOutputVar;isOutput=true]this is the value"
    name: setvarStep
  - script: echo $(setvarStep.myOutputVar)
    name: echovar

# Map the variable into job B
- job: B
  dependsOn: A
  pool:
    vmImage: 'ubuntu-16.04'
  variables:
    myVarFromJobA: $[ dependencies.A.outputs['setvarStep.myOutputVar'] ]  # map in the variable
                                                                          # remember, expressions require single quotes
  steps:
  - script: echo $(myVarFromJobA)
    name: echovar
```

Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61268214/ads-2019-how-to-pass-variables-between-build-jobs).

**Pass variable from stage to stage: which is not possible out of the box at the moment.**

Please check this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57485621/share-variables-across-stages-in-azure-devops-pipelines). Merlin Liang - MSFT explained this there.

**Workaround**

You can try write down to some file your variables, [publish it as pipelineartifact](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/artifacts/pipeline-artifacts?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml), download this artifact in another stage and load variables. Please check this [link](https://stefanstranger.github.io/2019/06/26/PassingVariablesfromStagetoStage/).

Comment: Finally I understood it, the **name of the step** is important! I was wondering why nothing came out on the other end of the job, I thought setvarStep was just the way this is referenced outside.